# R: Separating a string into 2 columns where separator character varies

Tags: r

I have a data frame called actorsdata

```html
> head(actorsdata)
                             ActorName
1     Aaron Taylor-Johnson (born 1990)
2                    Adele (born 1988)
3 Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje (born 1967)
4           Adrienne Posta (born 1948)
5              Afshan Azad (born 1988)
6                Al Weaver (born 1981)
```

I want to be able to split my single column ActorName into 3 columns: Actor Name, Born, Died

```html
> head(actorsdata)
      ActorName                         Born            Died
1     Aaron Taylor-Johnson              (born 1990)     NA
2                    Adele              (born 1988)     NA
3 Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje              (born 1967)     NA
```

Some rows contain year of death within brackets e.g. Angharad Rees (1944–2012)

Other rows contain multiple sets of parentheses e.g.Anna Carteret (born 1942) (born in Bangalore, India)

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you show all the patterns in the example input

Comment: You might wanna look into `tidyr`'s `separate`.